# Color Correction from two nearby Landsat8 Rasters in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, color

I have two Landsat8 images and they are side by side, but they are from different Dates. They look similar, but the color of the same forest is a bit different.

I tried a color correction in QGIS with the tool "r.blend - Blends color components of two raster maps by a given ratio" from GRASS GIS.
The result is not what I expected and wanted and the tool even combine the rectangular frame from the Raster.

Is there any other tool in QGis for a color correction from two Rasters?

I am a beginner in QGIS and I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: Have you done any atmospheric correction?

Comment: atmospheric correction is done.

Comment: What process was used for the atmospheric correction? Also, TOA or BOA?

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly, you are trying to make two different rasters, side by side, look similar to each other (e.g. contrast, colour balance etc). If so, this is easily done using the 'Colour Rendering' options located under that layer's Symbology.

Adjust the brightness, saturation and contrast until you get a result you are happy with. Hitting the apply button shows you the result almost immediately, negating the need for processing, saving etc.

If the 3 adjustments don't quite achieve what you need, adding a 'Hue' may help. Use this like a white balance on a camera, applying a blue tint on images that are too warm, and a red tint on images that are too cold.

Comment: Yes, I have two Rasters side by side from different Dates.
I never thougt about it. But it´s a good way to adjust the colors.
Using the Colour Rendering is just an optical change of the rasters, right? In this case the value of the pixel remains the same. If I do some calculations or processing on the rasters, there are maybe different results for each raster. 
Is there any kind of possibility, too adjust even the value of the pixel?

Comment: Correct - the Colour Rendering does not change pixel values. To make permanent changes to the raster, suggest trying Orfeo Toolbox (OTB). This is available within QGIS 2.18 (under the Processing Toolbox), but hasn't been brought over to QGIS 3 yet. If you are using QGIS 3.x, suggest trying the stand alone OTB program.

Answer (score 0):

This is a script I wrote that uses multiple regression with the scikit-learn package to compare pixel values with an input and target

```py
import numpy
import time
from sklearn import linear_model
from datetime import datetime

#Where the processing folder will be made
rootDirectory = 'D:/Other Tasks/Image Colour Matching/'

#The image that needs correction
initialImage = 'D:/Image Colour Matching/TintedImage.tif'

#The image that has the desired look
targetImage = 'D:/Image Colour Matching/GoogleSatImage.tif'

#Amount of correction to apply, 1.0 can be a bit extreme, 0.6 is a nice value to start with
correctionAmount = 0.6 

#Tif export options
compressOptions = 'COMPRESS=LZW|PREDICTOR=2|NUM_THREADS=8|BIGTIFF=IF_SAFER|TILED=YES'
compressOptionsFloat = 'COMPRESS=LZW|PREDICTOR=1|NUM_THREADS=8|BIGTIFF=IF_SAFER|TILED=YES'
gdalOptions = '--config GDAL_NUM_THREADS ALL_CPUS -overwrite'


"""
##############################################################################
Initial prep
"""

#Set up the layer name for the raster calculations
initImName = initialImage.split("/")
initImName = initImName[-1]
initImName = initImName[:len(initImName)-4]

directory = rootDirectory + initImName + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M") + '/'
try:
    os.mkdir(directory)
except BaseException as e:
    print(e)
    

#Determine pixel sizes for later resampling
initRas = QgsRasterLayer(initialImage)
pixelSizeXInit = initRas.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelSizeYInit = initRas.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
pixelSizeAveInit = (pixelSizeXInit + pixelSizeYInit) / 2

targetRas = QgsRasterLayer(targetImage)
pixelSizeXTarget = targetRas.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelSizeYTarget = targetRas.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
pixelSizeAveTarget = (pixelSizeXTarget + pixelSizeYTarget) / 2

pixelSizeMax = max(pixelSizeAveInit,pixelSizeAveTarget)
pixelSizeResamp = pixelSizeMax * 2

"""
##############################################################################
Image prep and sampling
"""

#Resample to the larger pixel size so that any parallax-type issues are mitigated
processing.run("gdal:translate", {'INPUT':targetImage,'TARGET_CRS':None,'NODATA':None,'COPY_SUBDATASETS':False,'OPTIONS':compressOptions,'EXTRA':'-tr ' + str(pixelSizeResamp) + ' ' + str(pixelSizeResamp) + ' -r cubic','DATA_TYPE':0,'OUTPUT':directory + 'TargetResample.tif'})
processing.run("gdal:translate", {'INPUT':initialImage,'TARGET_CRS':None,'NODATA':None,'COPY_SUBDATASETS':False,'OPTIONS':compressOptions,'EXTRA':'-tr ' + str(pixelSizeResamp) + ' ' + str(pixelSizeResamp) + ' -r cubic','DATA_TYPE':0,'OUTPUT':directory + 'InitialResample.tif'})

#Get the extent of the target raster
processing.run("gdal:translate", {'INPUT':targetImage,'TARGET_CRS':None,'NODATA':None,'COPY_SUBDATASETS':False,'OPTIONS':compressOptions,'EXTRA':'-b 4 -scale_1 128 255 -1000 1255','DATA_TYPE':0,'OUTPUT':directory + 'TargetAlpha.tif'})
processing.run("gdal:polygonize", {'INPUT':directory + 'TargetAlpha.tif','BAND':1,'FIELD':'DN','EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS':False,'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':directory + 'TargetAlphaExtent.gpkg'})
processing.run("native:fixgeometries", {'INPUT':directory + 'TargetAlphaExtent.gpkg','OUTPUT':directory + 'TargetAlphaExtentFix.gpkg'})
processing.run("native:extractbyexpression", {'INPUT':directory + 'TargetAlphaExtentFix.gpkg','EXPRESSION':' \"DN\" > 245','OUTPUT':directory + 'TargetAlphaExtentFilt.gpkg'})

#Get the extent of the initial raster
processing.run("gdal:translate", {'INPUT':initialImage,'TARGET_CRS':None,'NODATA':None,'COPY_SUBDATASETS':False,'OPTIONS':compressOptions,'EXTRA':'-b 4 -scale_1 128 255 -1000 1255','DATA_TYPE':0,'OUTPUT':directory + 'InitialAlpha.tif'})
processing.run("gdal:polygonize", {'INPUT':directory + 'InitialAlpha.tif','BAND':1,'FIELD':'DN','EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS':False,'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':directory + 'InitialAlphaExtent.gpkg'})
processing.run("native:fixgeometries", {'INPUT':directory + 'InitialAlphaExtent.gpkg','OUTPUT':directory + 'InitialAlphaExtentFix.gpkg'})
processing.run("native:extractbyexpression", {'INPUT':directory + 'InitialAlphaExtentFix.gpkg','EXPRESSION':' \"DN\" > 245','OUTPUT':directory + 'InitialAlphaExtentFilt.gpkg'})

#Find the intersection of the extents and buffer it in a touch
processing.run("native:clip", {'INPUT':directory + 'InitialAlphaExtentFilt.gpkg','OVERLAY':directory + 'TargetAlphaExtentFilt.gpkg','OUTPUT':directory + 'UnionExtent.gpkg'})
processing.run("native:buffer", {'INPUT':directory + 'UnionExtent.gpkg','DISTANCE':-1*pixelSizeResamp,'SEGMENTS':5,'END_CAP_STYLE':0,'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'DISSOLVE':False,'OUTPUT':directory + 'UnionExtentInBuff.gpkg'})

#Make a large amount of points for pixel value comparison
processing.run("native:randompointsinpolygons", {'INPUT':directory + 'UnionExtentInBuff.gpkg','POINTS_NUMBER':6000,'MIN_DISTANCE':0,'MIN_DISTANCE_GLOBAL':0,'MAX_TRIES_PER_POINT':10,'SEED':None,'INCLUDE_POLYGON_ATTRIBUTES':False,'OUTPUT':directory + 'RandomPoints.gpkg'})

#Sample the rasters so that the values can be compared
processing.run("native:rastersampling", {'INPUT':directory + 'RandomPoints.gpkg','RASTERCOPY':directory + 'TargetResample.tif','COLUMN_PREFIX':'PixelValTarget_','OUTPUT':directory + 'RandomPointsSampleTarget.gpkg'})
processing.run("native:rastersampling", {'INPUT':directory + 'RandomPointsSampleTarget.gpkg','RASTERCOPY':directory + 'InitialResample.tif','COLUMN_PREFIX':'PixelValInit_','OUTPUT':directory + 'RandomPointsSampleTargetInit.gpkg'})

"""
#############################################################################
Multiple regession
"""

#Get the points from the gpkg
points = QgsVectorLayer(directory + 'RandomPointsSampleTargetInit.gpkg')
l = [i.attributes() for i in points.getFeatures()]

#Get the values from the attribute table and put them into lists
[item[0] for item in l]
targetRed = [item[2] for item in l]
targetGreen = [item[3] for item in l]
targetBlue = [item[4] for item in l]
initialRed = [item[6] for item in l]
initialGreen = [item[7] for item in l]
initialBlue = [item[8] for item in l]

#Determine the residual between the initial and the target raster, as a way of trend removal
residualRed = [b - a for a, b in zip(initialRed, targetRed)]
residualGreen = [b - a for a, b in zip(initialGreen, targetGreen)]
residualBlue = [b - a for a, b in zip(initialBlue, targetBlue)]

#Create 4th order polynomal predictors for putting into the multiple regression
allPredictors = list(zip(initialRed,[x**2 for x in initialRed],[x**3 for x in initialRed],[x**4 for x in initialRed],initialGreen,[x**2 for x in initialGreen],[x**3 for x in initialGreen],[x**4 for x in initialGreen],initialBlue,[x**2 for x in initialBlue],[x**3 for x in initialBlue],[x**4 for x in initialBlue]))

#Prep the model from sklearn
regrRed = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regrGreen = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regrBlue = linear_model.LinearRegression()

#Correlate the residual of red to the predictors
X = allPredictors
y = residualRed
regrRed.fit(X, y)
print(regrRed.coef_)

#Then for green
X = allPredictors
y = residualGreen
regrGreen.fit(X, y)
print(regrGreen.coef_)

#Then for blue
X = allPredictors
y = residualBlue
regrBlue.fit(X, y)
print(regrBlue.coef_)

"""
##############################################################################
Prep tasks for multiprocessing (saves a bit of time)
"""

def redCalc(task):
    try:
        #Use the coefficients from the multiple regression to calculate the new values for the image
        processing.run("gdal:rastercalculator", {'INPUT_A':initialImage,'BAND_A':1,'INPUT_B':initialImage,'BAND_B':2,'INPUT_C':initialImage,'BAND_C':3,
        'FORMULA':'(((' +
        str(regrRed.coef_[0]) + ' * float64(A)) + (' + str(regrRed.coef_[1]) + ' * (float64(A)**2)) + (' + str(regrRed.coef_[2]) + ' * (float64(A)**3)) + (' + str(regrRed.coef_[3]) + ' * (float64(A)**4)) + (' + 
        str(regrRed.coef_[4]) + ' * float64(B)) + (' + str(regrRed.coef_[5]) + ' * (float64(B)**2)) + (' + str(regrRed.coef_[6]) + ' * (float64(B)**3)) + (' + str(regrRed.coef_[7]) + ' * (float64(B)**4)) + (' +
        str(regrRed.coef_[8]) + ' * float64(C)) + (' + str(regrRed.coef_[9]) + ' * (float64(C)**2)) + (' + str(regrRed.coef_[10]) + ' * (float64(C)**3)) + (' + str(regrRed.coef_[11]) + ' * (float64(C)**4)) + ' + 
        str(regrRed.intercept_) + ')*' + str(correctionAmount) + ') + float64(A)'
        ,'NO_DATA':None,'RTYPE':5,'OPTIONS':compressOptionsFloat + '|DISCARD_LSB=14','EXTRA':'--overwrite','OUTPUT':directory + 'RedCalced.tif'})
    except BaseException as e:
        print(e)

def greenCalc(task):
    try:
        #Same for green, note the correction amount being applied
        processing.run("gdal:rastercalculator", {'INPUT_A':initialImage,'BAND_A':1,'INPUT_B':initialImage,'BAND_B':2,'INPUT_C':initialImage,'BAND_C':3,
        'FORMULA':'(((' +
        str(regrGreen.coef_[0]) + ' * float64(A)) + (' + str(regrGreen.coef_[1]) + ' * (float64(A)**2)) + (' + str(regrGreen.coef_[2]) + ' * (float64(A)**3)) + (' + str(regrGreen.coef_[3]) + ' * (float64(A)**4)) + (' + 
        str(regrGreen.coef_[4]) + ' * float64(B)) + (' + str(regrGreen.coef_[5]) + ' * (float64(B)**2)) + (' + str(regrGreen.coef_[6]) + ' * (float64(B)**3)) + (' + str(regrGreen.coef_[7]) + ' * (float64(B)**4)) + (' +
        str(regrGreen.coef_[8]) + ' * float64(C)) + (' + str(regrGreen.coef_[9]) + ' * (float64(C)**2)) + (' + str(regrGreen.coef_[10]) + ' * (float64(C)**3)) + (' + str(regrGreen.coef_[11]) + ' * (float64(C)**4)) + ' + 
        str(regrGreen.intercept_) + ')*' + str(correctionAmount) + ') + float64(B)'
        ,'NO_DATA':None,'RTYPE':5,'OPTIONS':compressOptionsFloat + '|DISCARD_LSB=14','EXTRA':'--overwrite','OUTPUT':directory + 'GreenCalced.tif'})        
    except BaseException as e:
        print(e)

def blueCalc(task):
    try:
        #Same for blue, note the removal of 14 bits as 32 is excessive if there will be a later final 8 bit export
        processing.run("gdal:rastercalculator", {'INPUT_A':initialImage,'BAND_A':1,'INPUT_B':initialImage,'BAND_B':2,'INPUT_C':initialImage,'BAND_C':3,
        'FORMULA':'(((' +
        str(regrBlue.coef_[0]) + ' * float64(A)) + (' + str(regrBlue.coef_[1]) + ' * (float64(A)**2)) + (' + str(regrBlue.coef_[2]) + ' * (float64(A)**3)) + (' + str(regrBlue.coef_[3]) + ' * (float64(A)**4)) + (' + 
        str(regrBlue.coef_[4]) + ' * float64(B)) + (' + str(regrBlue.coef_[5]) + ' * (float64(B)**2)) + (' + str(regrBlue.coef_[6]) + ' * (float64(B)**3)) + (' + str(regrBlue.coef_[7]) + ' * (float64(B)**4)) + (' +
        str(regrBlue.coef_[8]) + ' * float64(C)) + (' + str(regrBlue.coef_[9]) + ' * (float64(C)**2)) + (' + str(regrBlue.coef_[10]) + ' * (float64(C)**3)) + (' + str(regrBlue.coef_[11]) + ' * (float64(C)**4)) + ' + 
        str(regrBlue.intercept_) + ')*' + str(correctionAmount) + ') + float64(C)'
        ,'NO_DATA':None,'RTYPE':5,'OPTIONS':compressOptionsFloat + '|DISCARD_LSB=14','EXTRA':'--overwrite','OUTPUT':directory + 'BlueCalced.tif'})
    except BaseException as e:
        print(e)

"""
##############################################################################
Run the tasks in parallel and wait for them to finish
"""

#Start up the tasks
redTask = QgsTask.fromFunction('RedCalc', redCalc)
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(redTask)
greenTask = QgsTask.fromFunction('GreenCalc', greenCalc)
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(greenTask)
blueTask = QgsTask.fromFunction('BlueCalc', blueCalc)
QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(blueTask)

#Wait til done
try:
    redTask.waitForFinished(timeout = 900000)
except BaseException as e:
    print(e)  
try:
    greenTask.waitForFinished(timeout = 900000)
except BaseException as e:
    print(e)  
try:
    blueTask.waitForFinished(timeout = 900000)
except BaseException as e:
    print(e)  

"""
##############################################################################
Final bringing together of bands
"""

#Grab the alpha band of the initial image ready for the vrt
processing.run("gdal:translate", {'INPUT':initialImage,'TARGET_CRS':None,'NODATA':None,'COPY_SUBDATASETS':False,'OPTIONS':compressOptionsFloat,'EXTRA':'-b 4','DATA_TYPE':6,'OUTPUT':directory + 'AlphaBand.tif'})

#Bring together the bands into a vrt
processing.run("gdal:buildvirtualraster", {'INPUT':[directory + 'RedCalced.tif',directory + 'GreenCalced.tif',directory + 'BlueCalced.tif',directory + 'AlphaBand.tif'],
'RESOLUTION':2,'SEPARATE':True,'PROJ_DIFFERENCE':True,'ADD_ALPHA':False,'ASSIGN_CRS':None,'RESAMPLING':0,'SRC_NODATA':'','EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':directory + 'Band123A.vrt'})

#Export this out to a tif
processing.run("gdal:warpreproject", {'INPUT':directory + 'Band123A.vrt','SOURCE_CRS':None,'TARGET_CRS':None,'RESAMPLING':0,'NODATA':None,'TARGET_RESOLUTION':None,'OPTIONS':compressOptionsFloat,'DATA_TYPE':0,'TARGET_EXTENT':None,
'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS':None,'MULTITHREADING':True,'EXTRA':'-co \"PHOTOMETRIC=RGB\" -srcalpha -dstalpha ' + gdalOptions,'OUTPUT':directory + initImName + 'Corrected.tif'})

#Build pyramids to view the final image more easily
processing.run("gdal:overviews", {'INPUT':directory + initImName + 'Corrected.tif','CLEAN':False,'LEVELS':'','RESAMPLING':0,'FORMAT':1,'EXTRA':''})

#Bring in the final product
layer1 = iface.addRasterLayer(directory + initImName + 'Corrected.tif', initImName + 'Corrected' , '')#bring in the layer you want
#From here you may need to manually apply per-band min/max stretches, saturation adjustments and tinting to get it closer to the target look
```

Below is what I was able to achieve correction-wise. The difference in time of year between the captures affected the grass colour between the images, and interfered with the regression a bit (hence the colouring being a bit too yellow). However I was able to make them look fairly similar

Before
[image]
After
[image]