# Merging TIFF images based on any of the single images

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, merge, color

[image][image]I have lot of tiff images for a small area. I need to merge all the images based on any one of the image(for color ref). Actually we merge the data in QGIS but all images all slightly variation in their RGB color.

Comment: Are these images adjacent, do they overlap, do they represent the same area?

Comment: YES.SAME AREA.IMAGES ARE ADJACENT.

Comment: HERE I DONT KNOW HOW TO ATTACH MY SCREENSHOTS FOR YOUR REFERENCE

Comment: You need to edit your original question to add the screenshot. And please, don't write in uppercase unless you need to emphasize a word or something.

Comment: Thanks for the command. Now I had attached the screenshots for your reference

Comment: How can I solve these issues in Qgis?

Comment: Does this help? (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289473/color-correction-from-two-nearby-landsat8-rasters-in-qgis)

Comment: No. I cant satisfied that results

Comment: The linked post says to adjust using brightness, contrast, hue, etc... to have matching colours. You have to do those adjustments manually. Were you able to do that? What part didn't work for you?

Comment: No. Actually I need all images like based on any one image color. I had to adjust those contrast, bright etc. but we cant get proper solution

Comment: There is no perfect solution, especially when images are acquired at different times. As far as I know, there isn't a way to do this in QGIS. Perhaps try in image editing software like Photoshop or Inkscape. You may look into histogram matching.